# Query returning incorrect value for negative time zone

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have a rails application where i need to get the count of records those where updated after a specific datetime value.

```
Records.count(:all, :conditions => "updated_at > '#{date_time_value}'")
```

When i tried using the query above i am getting the records count incorrect if the time zone is in a negative value.

Any idea how to make it work for all the time zone values?

Comment: which class is you date_time_value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need stock your date in UTC and request it only with UTC date.

If date_time_value is a date call .utc to do the change.